# Python create dictionary with key and list of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of integers where the index represents the column number of a pandas dataframe. I want to save the name of the dataframe column and the value of the lists index, so i thought of using a dictionary with the lists value as key and `dataframe.loc[list_index]` as value.
There are multiple values for one key, so i give an example for the list of integers:

```
[0,2,1,5,0,9,6,3]
```

So i want to have a dicitonary like this:

```
0: [column1, another column]
1: [column3,...]
....
```

Here is my first approach:

```
article_nos= {}
for idx, val in enumerate(labels):
    try:
        article_nos[val].append(data_pct_change.loc[:, idx].name)
    except KeyError:
        article_nos[val] = [val]
```

*Data:*
data_pct_change:

```
ARTICLE_NO     43470868       40370875       43770899       48870943       \
DATE                                                                     
2017-01-02       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000   
2017-01-09      -0.015625      -0.074928      -0.083333       0.230769   
2017-01-16       0.232804       0.007788       0.284091       0.062500   
2017-01-23       0.051502       0.174652       0.011799       0.117647   
2017-01-30       0.200000      -0.082895       0.008746       0.807018   
2017-02-06       0.057823       0.040172      -0.020231      -0.411003   
2017-02-13       0.000000      -0.037241      -0.014749      -0.087912   
2017-02-20       0.125402       0.259312       0.218563       0.138554   
2017-02-27      -0.265714      -0.271900      -0.233415      -0.343915   
2017-03-06       0.470817       0.293750       0.448718       0.661290   
2017-03-13       0.002646       0.013285      -0.057522      -0.048544
```

labels:

```
[27, 5, 5, 6, 27, 27, 27, 27,...]
```

Desired output:

```
27: [43470868,...]
5: [40370875, 43770899, ...]
```

This should clarify what i try to achieve.

So i want to use the index of the list which contains labels of a kmeans algorithm and create a dictionary with all created labels and the column names of the dataframe that belong to the specific column, so the value is my key and data_pct_change.loc[:, idx] should be my value and appended in each iteration.
However, this does not work, only the except block is executed.
Can someone help?

Comment: The code and data you provided does not help understanding what exactly are you trying to achieve. Could you please post the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (values of `labels`, `data_pct_change` and the expected result are necessary).

Comment: I want to access the columns of a dataframe (data_pct_change) by the index which is equal to the index of the number in labels. the value to this specified index should be used as key in the dictionary to be created so i get all columns of the data_pct_change that match a certain value from labels as list of values to their specific key

Comment: Please have a read what [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and edit your question to conform. Otherwise it is unclear and nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't completely understand what you're going for. But here's something that might make your life easier.`tempList = your_Df.columns.values` this will return you a list of the column names of your dataframe while preserving order. So if you had a dataframe with the columns `a d g b c f` you would get this list : `['a' 'd' 'g' 'b' 'c' 'f']`.

This should at least help you iterate over the column names while preserving the right index.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i looked for. now i can connect my two lists the desired way